# Remove duplicates in multi-element string[] array?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, .net-4.0

I have a string[] array that is split by `\r`. Each row in the array has title|address in it, but every so often I end up with a duplicate of the address portion of it, which I don't want.

This:

```
Title1 | Address1 //[0]
Title2 | Address2 //[1]
Title3 | Address1 //[2]
Title4 | Address3 //[3]
```

Would become:

```
Title1 | Address1 //[0]
Title2 | Address2 //[1]
Title4 | Address3 //[2]
```

The array declaration is as follows: `string[] resultsArray = results.Split('\r'); //Title|Address` I then later split the row when I grab the individual elements by `|`.

Usage (extremely simplified):

```
foreach (string result in resultsArray)
{
    string splitResult[] = result.Split('|');
    title = splitResult[0];
    address = splitResult[1];
}
```

Comment: So if there is a duplicate address, you want to remove the title aswell? Have you tried using a `Dictionary<string,string>` instead?

Comment: Why did you remove Title3 and not Title1?

Comment: @moriartyn The OP is asking about a **multi element** array

Comment: @The Scrum Meister Oh, Thanks, I should have looked at it better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming the question is, how do you prevent duplicate addresses from being entered into the list.  Could you use a [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx)?

```
Dictionary<string, string> addresses = new Dictionary<string, string>();

foreach(string result in resultsArray)
{
    string splitResult[] = result.Split('|');

    // check to see if address already exists, if it does, skip it.
    if(!addresses.ContainsKey(splitResult[1]))
    {
        addresses.add(splitResult[1], splitResult[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, your interpretation is a better one than my own. I ended up using: if (!resultsList.Exists(delegate(ResultsList r) { return r.title == splitResult[0]; }))

Comment: As I've been loading the results into a comprehensive list with other elements.

Answer (score 3):

```
string[] strings = { "Title1 | Address1", "Title2 | Address2", "Title3 | Address1", "Title4 | Address3" };
var _strings = strings.GroupBy(s => s.Split('|')[1]).Select(g => g.Min(s => s));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var seenItBefore = new HashSet<string>();
foreach (string result in resultsArray)
{
    string splitResult[] = result.Split('|');
    title = splitResult[0];
    address = splitResult[1];

    if (!seenItBefore.Add(address)) continue;

    // process
}
```

You could also supply a projecting `IEqualityComparer<string[]>`to `Distinct()` if you're building up a vine of `IEnumerable<>`, but since your sample doesn't use it, I decided to stick with classic procedural.

Comment: The `Add` method returns a bool to indicate whether the item was already in the set, so you could just use `if (!seenItBefore.Add(address)) { /* process */ }` instead of the `Contains`/`Add` combo.

Comment: @LukeH I think you got the condition inverted, since `Add` returns true if the add succeeds.  Incorporating the change, though.

Answer (score 1):

Using John Skeet's [`ProjectionComparer`](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2008/08/06/making-the-most-of-generic-type-inference.aspx), it becomes rather easy:

```
var comparer = new ProjectionComparer((string input) => input.Split('|')[1]);
var results = resultsArray.Distinct(comparer);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
resultArray.Select(p => p.Split('|')).Select(p => new { Name = p[0], Address = p[1] }).GroupBy(p => p.Address).Select(p => p.First()).ToArray();
```